# Python: Can you use raw_input and template strings? (%s)

Tags: python

I have this line of code..

```
raw_input("Hello, %s, this is a question: ") % name
```

but i get and error saying:

> "Not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Is it possible to use `%s` when using `input()`?

Answer (score 5):

`name` is in the wrong spot; change to:

```
raw_input("Hello, %s, this is a question: " % name)
```

for example:

```
>>> name = 'Mary'
>>> raw_input('Hello, %s, this is a question:' % name)
Hello, Mary, this is a question:
```