# Python: raw_input and template string syntax error

Tags: python-2.7, syntax-error

I've got these lines of code:

```
league = 'something'    
wherel = raw_input('NEW LEAGUE - %s - insert 1 to put in good leagues, insert 2 to put in bad leagues ', % league)
```

and there seems to be a sintax error in it.

I did check this answer:

[Python: Can you use raw_input and template strings? (%s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150483/python-can-you-use-raw-input-and-template-strings-s)

and it should be working, but I really can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Copy & paste the solution from that link. Is it _exactly_ the same as your code? Does it have a comma after the last quote symbol?

Answer (score 0):

You have an `,` in raw_input

```
league = 'something'    
wherel = raw_input('NEW LEAGUE - %s - insert 1 to put in good leagues, insert 2 to put in bad leagues ', % league)
```

ref: [String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting)

Comment: Man... I didn't notice... I have been looking at that for 1 hour... Thanks